# How to remove particular marker form google map when user start retype another place name in textbox

Tags: vue.js, markers

I'm trying to remove place marker form map. when user perform keypress event in input field.in my project i have two gmap-autocomplete components the both creat diffrent markers on map.so when i use setMap(null) then it remove all the markes form map.i need to remove one at a time.Please help Thank you.!

```
 refreshMapEndSource(event) {
      if (document.getElementById('txtDestination').value != '') {
        let endOrigin = document.getElementById('txtDestination').value
        if (this.markRemEnd != null) {
          if (endOrigin != this.markRemEnd.fplace) {
            console.log('NOt Equal')
             console.log(this.$google.marker[i].fplace)
              this.$google.marker[0].setMap(null)
          }
        }
      } else {
        //
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what are you trying to do but I guess you want to remove markers which created from either A or B component.

To do this when you create marker you have to keep it in some array let's call it as `markers`:

```javascript
let markers = []

let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: location,
  map: map
})

markers.push({
  type: 'A' // or 'B',
  marker
})
```

Then whenever you want to remove markers from A:

```javascript
markers.forEach(marker => {
  if (marker.type === 'A') marker.marker.setMap(null)
})

markers = this.markers.filter(marker => marker.type !== 'A')
```

Well if my guess is wrong and you really want to remove particular marker which is pretty similar you have to know which marker you have remove.

```javascript
markers.push({
  name: 'abc',
  marker
})

markers.forEach(marker => {
  if (marker.name === 'abc') marker.marker.setMap(null)
})
```

Comment: Thank you Sir for your answer.you guess is perfect.

Comment: If this answer you question you can accept it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.